# hibernate foo.hbm.xml not-null="true" only relevant for writing?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

```
<property name="name" column="name" type="string" not-null="true" access="field" />
```

Having this kind of hibernate customer.hbm.xml, does this appies for reading and writing?

When I have a not-null="true" will hibernate crash even on reading a null or only when trying to write null?

Answer (score 0):

I have been fooled by the error message. It looked like it was a read operation, but was an write